# Is there a critical hit spot on a shank?

Tags: destiny

In Destiny, so much depends on precision kills for hunters. Shanks usually go down very easy, but is there a critical hit spot for them? If for no other reason than getting the precision kill.

Answer (score 2):

Shanks do not have any critical spots. Their health is far too low to even justify aiming for a critical spot.

Comment: I feel like the penetration stat of weapons matters more for shanks. I've noticed that with some weapons they go down harder than Dregs and sometimes easier. But this might just be selection bias on my part noticing it.

Answer (score -3):

I believe I have gotten a crit on a shank from behind. I don't think there's a crit spot from the front.

Answer (score -5):

I remember getting one, i just do not remember where, exactly, but, I believe it is in the center of the central mother board, on the face